# python 3.4 filtering a text file into lists

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble in filtering a .txt file into sublists which I can then turn into a directory.
A sample from the text.txt
`A2.-B4-...C4-.-.D3-..E1.F4..-.G3--.H4....75--...85---..95----.05-----.6.-.-.-,6--..--?6..--..!5..--.`
 with no spaces or linebreaks, it's basically a line of text.
 A2.- means that the symbol 'A' has 2 characters in morse-code, and they are .-, etc
What I would like to do is split this long string into sublists, that I can then zip together into a directory that I can then use to make a morse-code translator. What I would like the program to do: make a list keyList that contains the keys A,B,C,...,?,.,
 and another list valueList that contains the values for the keys.
However since the keys are not all letters im having problems filtering through the entire file. 
What I have tried:

```
import re
r = open("text.txt", "r")
ss = r.read()    
p = re.compile('\w'+'\w')
keyList = p.findall(ss)
ValueList = p.split(ss)
print(keyList)
print(ValueList)
```

```
keyList = ['A2', 'B4', 'C4', 'D3',..., '75', '85', '95', '05']
ValueList = ['', '.-', '-...', '-.-.', '-..', space , !5..--.']
```

As seen the valuelist will not split correctly, because '\w'+'\w' will only match alpha-numerical characters.. I have tried changing the argument on re.compile but have not found anything that has worked. Any help? is re.compiled the best way to do this or is there another way to filter through the text?

EDIT: expected/wanted output:

```
keyList = ['A','B','C','D',...,'.','?',',']
ValueList = ['.-','-...','-.-.','-..',...,'.-.-.-','..--..','--..--']
```

Comment: do you want just the letters ? like `A` , `B` , .. ? can you add your expected output to question ?

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what I would like, however the list does not only contain letters, even '.' has a morse-code that is .-.-.- <br/>So I'd like '.' to be a key aswell with the value '.-.-.-'<br/>

Comment: so what about the numbers? its better to add the desire output !

Answer (score 1):

To make an encoder/decoder, you probably want to use dictionaries rather than lists.

As far as parsing it, a direct naive approach is probably best here.

```
result = {}
with open('morse.txt', 'r') as f:    
    while True:    
        key = f.read(1)                                                   
        length_str = f.read(1)                                            

        if len(key) != 1 or len(length_str) != 1:                         
            break                                                         

        try:                                                              
            length = int(length_str)                                      
        except ValueError:                                                
            break                                                         

        value = f.read(length)                                            

        if len(value) == length:                                          
            result[key] = value                                           

for k, v in result.items():
    print k, v
```

results in:

```
A .-
! ..--.                                                                   
C -.-.                                                                    
B -...                                                                    
E .                                                                       
D -..                                                                     
G --.                                                                     
F ..-.                                                                    
H ....                                                                    
, --..--                                                                  
. .-.-.-                                                                  
0 -----                                                                   
7 --...                                                                   
9 ----.                                                                   
8 ---..                                                                   
? ..--..
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following :

```
items = re.findall(r'(.\d)([\.-]+)', ss)
keys = [s[0][0] for s in items]
values = [s[1] for s in items]
```

I got :

```
>>> keys
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', '7', '8', '9', '0', ',', '?', '!']
values
['.-', '-...', '-.-.', '-..', '.', '..-.', '--.', '....', '--...', '---..', '----.', '-----.', '--..--', '..--..', '..--.']
```

Comment: This is a lot more succinct than my answer. I guess the length serves no purpose beyond being a delimiter!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Cuadue's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27235233/2449192), I would use a loop to parse this, but I would do it in reverse order instead:

```
morse_str = 'A2.-B4-...C4-.-.D3-..E1.F4..-.G3--.H4....75--...85---..95----.05-----.6.-.-.-,6--..--?6..--..!5..--.'
morse_list = list(morse_str)
morse_dict = {}
while morse_list:
    morse = ''
    while True:
        sym = morse_list.pop()
        try:
            int(sym)
        except ValueError:
            morse += sym
        else:
            key = morse_list.pop()
            morse_dict[key] = morse[::-1]
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

For find the keys you can use [positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in regular expressions  :

```
>>> s = 'A2.-B4-...C4-.-.D3-..E1.F4..-.G3--.H4....75--...85---..95----.05-----.6.-.-.-,6--..--?6..--..!5..--.'
>>> keys = re.findall(r'[\w|\W](?=\d\W)',s)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', '7', '8', '9', '0', '.', ',', '?', '!']
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CCjhKyCeIZpTSa_W)

As you have none letter characters like `!` and `,.` in both your keys and values, you couldn't use jut one `re` function for get the expected values , you can use that pattern with `split()` function to split the string based on your keys so then you will have the expected values output with just a digit at the leading , then remove that digit with `re.sub()` :

```
>>> values = [re.sub('\d','',i) for i in re.split(r'[\w|\W](?=\d)',s) if len(i)]
['.-', '-...', '-.-.', '-..', '.', '..-.', '--.', '...', '--..', '---.', '----', '-----', '.-.-.-', '--..--', '..--..', '..--.']
```

so as an important things you must have the same `len` for `keys` and `values` :

```
>>> len(keys)
16
>>> len(values)
16
```

and finally zip them :

```
>>> dict(zip(keys,values))
{'A': '.-', '!': '..--.', 'C': '-.-.', 'B': '-...', 'E': '.', 'D': '-..', 'G': '--.', 'F': '..-.', 'H': '...', ',': '--..--', '.': '.-.-.-', '0': '-----', '7': '--..', '9': '----', '8': '---.', '?': '..--..'}
```